# Find http protocol in some links and convert it to https

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace

On my little code, I'm loading a script that changes the colors of links but I also want to replace the `http` where needed with `https` using some Regex but I'm facing an error with `replace` function in JS.

The Regex for JS would only replace to `https://` when a string starts with `http://` (case-insensitive), otherwise the original string is returned as is.

The code so far looks like in the snippet, the colors are changing for all the links but `replace` has issues.

Please let me know what's wrong with the code so far.

```js
window.onload = function() {
          // alert('Page loaded');
          let url = document.querySelectorAll('.page-numbers');
          console.log(url);
          url.forEach((e) => {
            e.style.color = 'red';
            console.log(e);
            e.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');
          }); 
        };
```

```html
<div class="pagingSection">
  <a href="http://www.example.com" class="page-numbers">Link 1</a>
  <a href="https://www.example.com" class="page-numbers">Link 2</a>
  <a href="http://www.example.com" class="page-numbers">Link 3</a>
  <a href="//www.example.com" class="page-numbers">Link 4</a>
  <a href="" class="page-numbers">Link 5</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS if you have to edit an attribute of an HTML element you should use `setAttribute`.

Also you are getting an error because the `url` variable is not an array of string, it's an array HTML element so it dont have a replace function, you should use `e.href` to read the url

```js
window.onload = function() {
          // alert('Page loaded');
          let url = document.querySelectorAll('.page-numbers');
          
          url.forEach((e) => {
            e.style.color = 'red';
            e.setAttribute('href', e.href.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://'));
   
            console.log(e);

          }); 
        };
```

```html
<div class="pagingSection">
  <a href="http://www.example.com" class="page-numbers">Link 1</a>
  <a href="https://www.example.com" class="page-numbers">Link 2</a>
  <a href="http://www.example.com" class="page-numbers">Link 3</a>
  <a href="//www.example.com" class="page-numbers">Link 4</a>
  <a href="" class="page-numbers">Link 5</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the `href` property of the link:

Take a look at this snippet. I only modified the `e.replace` line.

```js
window.onload = function() {
          // alert('Page loaded');
          let url = document.querySelectorAll('.page-numbers');
          console.log(url);
          url.forEach((e) => {
            e.style.color = 'red';
            console.log(e);
            e.href = e.href.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');

          }); 
        };
```

```html
<div class="pagingSection">
  <a href="http://www.example.com" class="page-numbers">Link 1</a>
  <a href="https://www.example.com" class="page-numbers">Link 2</a>
  <a href="http://www.example.com" class="page-numbers">Link 3</a>
  <a href="//www.example.com" class="page-numbers">Link 4</a>
  <a href="" class="page-numbers">Link 5</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Totally escaped `href` part